# «Они не принесут вам ничего(,) кроме неприятностей». Стоит ли обособлять ''кроме"?

Tags: пунктуация

«...они не принесут вам ничего кроме неприятностей». Стоит ли отделить запятой *кроме* в данном случае?

Answer (score 2):

**... они не принесут вам ничего, кроме неприятностей.**

См. [КРОМЕ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_370) (кого, чего), предлог

Обороты с предлогом «кроме» обычно обособляются, если предлог можно заменить словами «исключая, не считая кого-либо, чего-либо».

На моих глазах произошло следующее возмутительное происшествие, рисующее яркими красками наши железнодорожные порядки... (далее всё зачеркнуто, кроме подписи). А. Чехов, Жалобная книга. Ничья судьба, кроме своей собственной, вас более не интересует. М. Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита. И все, кроме неподвижного прокуратора, проводили взглядом Марка Крысобоя... М. Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита. Ну кто еще, кроме советских людей, станет в штормовую погоду разыгрывать отказанный ферзевой гамбит! И. Ильф, Е. Петров, Одноэтажная Америка.

Запятые могут не ставиться, если предлог «кроме» имеет значение «дополнительно, вдобавок к чему-либо».

Достопримечательностью главной комнаты кроме рояля было громадное полотно в тяжелой позолоченной раме, написанное неизвестным художником… Б. Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов.

Однако и при таком значении предлога постановка запятых возможна.

Кроме радиоуправляемого ликвидатора, манекен снабжен встроенным напоминателем... В. Пелевин, Встроенный напоминатель.